# Dapper SimpleCRUD casts: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Tags: c#, asp.net, dapper, guid, dapper-simplecrud

I'm building an API for basic CRUD operations on a database table. I'm using C# in an ASP.NET Web API project and my service classes live in a separate class library. Dapper and Dapper.SimpleCRUD used for ORM operations.

When I hard code a guid into the database using `DEFAULT NEWID()`, my create methods work fine. But for best practice I want to create a new guid in the controller class and then send it to the DB. When I do this it fails.

In the Controller:

```
var newParty = new Party()
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(), //this is when I started getting the cast error
    Name = party.Name,
    CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
};
```

In the repository:

```
public int? Create(Party obj)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var result = connection.Insert(obj);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I get an `"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.IConvertible'."` response.

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Convert.ToInt64(Object value)\r\n   at Dapper.SimpleCRUD.Insert[TKey](IDbConnection connection, Object entityToInsert, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable`1 commandTimeout) in C:\\Users\\ecoffman\\Documents\\GitHub\\Dapper.SimpleCRUD\\Dapper.SimpleCRUD\\SimpleCRUD.cs:line 364\r\n   at KC.QMS.CrudRepository`1.Create(T obj) in D:\\Isoright\\src\\WebApp\\KC.QMS\\CrudRepository.cs:line 86\r\n   at KC.QMS.Services.InterestedPartyService.CreateInterestedParty(InterestedParty interestedParty) in D:\\Isoright\\src\\WebApp\\KC.QMS\\Services\\InterestedPartyService.cs:line 27\r\n   at IsoRight.Api.Controllers.InterestedPartyController.CreateInterestedParty(InterestedParty interestedParty) in D:\\Isoright\\src\\Api\\IsoRight.Api\\Controllers\\InterestedPartyController.cs:line 73
```

Comment: https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/issues/97 (found by Googling for `SimpleCRUD GUID System.IConvertible`)

Comment: To be honest - this library is unreliable and quite buggy. It's much easier to write your own simple DAL with Dapper

Comment: Yes it did thanks @mjwills. I couldn't solve it alone. Took a bit of tweaking from a more senior dev due to the complexity of the code in the service class. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The generic Insert method is designed for int primary keys. You can pass in the type as the first parameter. Here is an example:

```
 connection.Insert<Guid, T>;
```

See the unit tests for this here: 
hhttps://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/blob/master/Dapper.SimpleCRUDTests/Tests.cs#L682